# Do the following sequences of functions converge pointwise or uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Determine whether the following functions converge pointless or uniformly on $[0, \infty)$.

1)
$$
 f_{n}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
 x - n & x \ge n \\
 0 & x < n
\end{cases}
$$
2)
$$
 f_{n}(x) = 
\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{x}
$$

I know that 1 converges pointwise to 0, but I am unsure whether it converges uniformly or not. I have no clue about the convergence of 2.

Answer (score 1):

(1) does not converge uniformly. For every $n$, there exists $x \in [0,\rightarrow]$ with $f(x) = 1$. (Taking $x = n+1$) $[0,\rightarrow]$ means all real numbers greater than or equal to $0$.

For (2), notice that $\sqrt{x + (1/n)} \leq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{1/n}$.

Comment: So, for (2), $fn(x)<=\sqrt{1/n}$. I believe this function converges uniformly, but I am not sure if this is correct/why.

Comment: @britgirl5 $\sqrt{1/n}$ is constant w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite understand your notation used in the comment on (1). Could you maybe explain this a little more?

Comment: @britgirl5 $[0,\rightarrow]$ meams all real numbers greater than or equal to $0$.